# How to Calculate the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x-c}$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

How to Calculate the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x-c}$? $c$ here is a complex number which does not lie on the real line. First I should figure out how to interpret this function as a tempered distribution. I suppose that it should be a $L^2$ function because its singularity is not on the real line and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is integrable with $0$ removed. Is that correct? If so, how to calculate its Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1):

Your correct that $\frac 1{x-c}\in L^2(\mathbb R)$.
Also, notice that if $a\in \mathbb C- i\mathbb R$, with $\Re (a)>0$, $$\int _{0}^{+\infty}e^{2i\pi x\xi} e^{-a\xi}d\xi=-\frac {1}{2i\pi x -a}$$
So you should be able to finish :-)

Comment: Can you be more detailed? To calculate the Fourier transform, aren't we suppose to look at $\langle \frac{1}{x-c}, F\phi \rangle$ where $\phi$ is a schwarz function.

Comment: The Fourier transform has a precise définition via an integral. So does the inverse Fourier transform. Try writing that integral for the function $e^{-a\xi}H(\xi)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.